# Code Golf: Diamond Blackjack

Tags: language-agnostic, code-golf, rosetta-stone

### The challenge

The shortest code by character count to output a best-case blackjack hand from the list of number-cards given.

Input is a list of numbers from 1 to 10 (inclusive) separated by space.

Output will be the best blackjack hand formed from that list of cards - the closest available combo to reach 21 by the sum of all card values without surpassing it. Cards can be removed but not added.

If a case where removing two or more cards in favor of one card to accomplish the same result (removing 5 or 4,1 to gain 21) removing the least cards is required. 
If the equal amount of cards is to be removed (removing 1,4 or 3,2) the group with the minimum of the minimum will be removed (in the previous example, 1,4 will be removed as `min(min(3,2), min(1,4))` belongs to that pair). In the case of duplicate cards, the first encounter should be removed.

Output will be formed as diamond cards, with input order preserved:

```
 __________  __________ 
|          ||          |
|          || /\       |
|          || \/       |
|    /\    ||          |
|    \/    ||          |
|          ||       /\ |
|          ||       \/ |
|__________||__________|
 __________  __________ 
|          ||          |
| /\       || /\    /\ |
| \/       || \/    \/ |
|    /\    ||          |
|    \/    ||          |
|       /\ || /\    /\ |
|       \/ || \/    \/ |
|__________||__________|
 __________  __________ 
|          ||          |
| /\    /\ || /\    /\ |
| \/    \/ || \/    \/ |
|    /\    || /\    /\ |
|    \/    || \/    \/ |
| /\    /\ || /\    /\ |
| \/    \/ || \/    \/ |
|__________||__________|
 __________  __________ 
|          ||          |
| /\    /\ || /\    /\ |
| \/ /\ \/ || \/ /\ \/ |
| /\ \/ /\ || /\ \/ /\ |
| \/    \/ || \/ /\ \/ |
| /\    /\ || /\ \/ /\ |
| \/    \/ || \/    \/ |
|__________||__________|
 __________  __________ 
| /\    /\ || /\    /\ |
| \/    \/ || \/ /\ \/ |
| /\    /\ || /\ \/ /\ |
| \/ /\ \/ || \/    \/ |
| /\ \/ /\ || /\    /\ |
| \/    \/ || \/ /\ \/ |
| /\    /\ || /\ \/ /\ |
|_\/____\/_||_\/____\/_|
```

### Test cases

```
Input:
    1 5 7 8
Output:
     __________  __________  __________  __________ 
    |          ||          ||          ||          |
    |          || /\    /\ || /\    /\ || /\    /\ |
    |          || \/    \/ || \/ /\ \/ || \/ /\ \/ |
    |    /\    ||    /\    || /\ \/ /\ || /\ \/ /\ |
    |    \/    ||    \/    || \/    \/ || \/ /\ \/ |
    |          || /\    /\ || /\    /\ || /\ \/ /\ |
    |          || \/    \/ || \/    \/ || \/    \/ |
    |__________||__________||__________||__________|
```

---

```
Input: 
    10 3 4 2 6
Output:
     __________  __________  __________  __________ 
    | /\    /\ ||          ||          ||          |
    | \/ /\ \/ || /\       || /\       || /\    /\ |
    | /\ \/ /\ || \/       || \/       || \/    \/ |
    | \/    \/ ||    /\    ||          || /\    /\ |
    | /\    /\ ||    \/    ||          || \/    \/ |
    | \/ /\ \/ ||       /\ ||       /\ || /\    /\ |
    | /\ \/ /\ ||       \/ ||       \/ || \/    \/ |
    |_\/____\/_||__________||__________||__________|
```

---

```
Input 
    5 10 5 2 3
Output:
     __________  __________  __________  __________ 
    | /\    /\ ||          ||          ||          |
    | \/ /\ \/ || /\    /\ || /\       || /\       |
    | /\ \/ /\ || \/    \/ || \/       || \/       |
    | \/    \/ ||    /\    ||          ||    /\    |
    | /\    /\ ||    \/    ||          ||    \/    |
    | \/ /\ \/ || /\    /\ ||       /\ ||       /\ |
    | /\ \/ /\ || \/    \/ ||       \/ ||       \/ |
    |_\/____\/_||__________||__________||__________|
```

Code count includes input/output (i.e full program).

Comment: Should the first example be `1 5 7 8` ?

Comment: Yes yes, I'm a human, I make mistakes. Please forgive and forget :P

Comment: Well of course somebody already fixed it. :)

Comment: Should I take that down-vote personally and just stop posting code-golf questions? I know a lot of people enjoy them... Oh well...

Comment: I never participate in code gold but I like them so I upvoted.

Comment: +1: I would ignore the downvoters. Lots of people look forward to code golf and really like it, and those who don't always have an ignore list at their disposal.

Comment: +1 - I find code golf useless, and a complete waste of time, but just like the movies, enjoy it from time to time, nevertheless. Carry on Lira... ;)

Comment: @LiraNuna: maybe you should take it personally, cos they wouldn't be voting against such a nice question

Comment: @LiraNuna: That sounds vaguely like Tiger's recent mea culpa, and given that this is Code _Golf_, how utterly appropriate.

Comment: For `1 10 8` would the answer be 1,10 or 1,10,8? Does 1 represent an ace?

Comment: `1 10 8` will be `1 10 8`... 19 is closer to 21 than 18 and does not surpass it.

Comment: @LiraNuna: So this is not blackjack? From Wikipedia: `Cards with a number 2 to 10 printed on them count as that value; the jack, queen, and king (also known as "face cards") count as 10; and the ace card can be either 1 or 11 at the player's choice.`

Comment: @gwell: it's a "custom" blackjack made for the challenge. I called it blackjack because of the number 21.

Comment: +1 : I really look forward to your weekly problems and this one did not disappoint!

Comment: I need some time to get more ideas. Some holiday break for now!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Golfscript - 228 Characters

```
' ':x/{~}%:h;9,{:r;h,2\?,{:m;h,,{2\?m&},{h\=}%}%1>{:j[{+}*.22<\j,j$j]}$)\;{:c;[x]3,{4\?'  \//\__'2/[11'?'*8'@'*'bb@BBbbbbbQY@AAQQQYYbfH@H@HbffYQD@D@DQQYfb@``bbbbfQY@PPQQQQQbf'8'?'*]']]'+10r*c+=@/3&=}%[x]++' _'1/7r&!=*}%'|':x;n}%
```

```
$ echo 10 9 8 7 6 5 | ../golfscript.rb black.gs
 __________  __________  __________ 
|          ||          ||          |
| /\    /\ || /\    /\ || /\    /\ |
| \/ /\ \/ || \/ /\ \/ || \/    \/ |
| /\ \/ /\ || /\ \/ /\ || /\    /\ |
| \/ /\ \/ || \/    \/ || \/    \/ |
| /\ \/ /\ || /\    /\ || /\    /\ |
| \/    \/ || \/    \/ || \/    \/ |
|__________||__________||__________|
```

**231 Characters**

```
' ':x/{~}%:h,2\?,{:m;h,,{2\?m&},{h\=}%}%1>{:j[{+}*.22<\j,j$j]}$-1=:h;9,{:r;h{:c;[x]3,{4\?'  \//\__'2/11'?'*8'@'*'bb@BBbbbbbQY@AAQQQYYbfH@H@HbffYQD@D@DQQYfb@``bbbbfQY@PPQQQQQbf'8'?'*']]'++++10r*c+=@/3&=}%[x]++' _'1/7r&!=*}%'|':x;n}%
```

**how it works**

```
# parse input into a list 
' ':x/{~}%:h
# create the powerset
 ,2\?,{:m;h,,{2\?m&},
# map the powerset onto the cards
{h\=}%}%
# trim the empty set from the powerset
1>
# sort the hands. most preferred hand will be last
{:j[{+}*.22<\j,j$j]}$
# take the preferred hand from the end of the list
-1=:h;
# for r in 0..8
9,{:r
...more to follow
```

Comment: what are you guy's opinion on golfscript in code-golf competitions? :D

Comment: Sometimes I wonder..seemed to need rather a lot of variables for this one

Answer (score 11):

### [J](http://www.jsoftware.com), 303 characters

```
4(1!:2)~,&(10{a.)"1>,.&.>/4 :'''/\/\''(x(<@:+)"1]4 2$1|.4#0 1)}y'&.>/@((<>1 7 1#1&|.@(2 10&#)&.>' _';'| ';'|_'),~>)"0(>({~[:(i.[:>./[*22&>)+/@>)(#:@i.@(2&^)@#<@#"1 _])".1!:1]3){a:,(((1$7);(a 0 _1;7),(a 0 2 _3 _1;7),((a=:,&.>/\)0 2 6 8 _3 _1;4;_5)){&.><,{(2+i.5);2 5 8),(4 5;k);<2 5;6 5;k=:,{2 8;~>:+:i.4
```

```
$ echo -n 1 5 7 8 | jconsole test.ijs
 __________  __________  __________  __________
|          ||          ||          ||          |
|          || /\    /\ || /\    /\ || /\    /\ |
|          || \/    \/ || \/ /\ \/ || \/ /\ \/ |
|    /\    ||    /\    || /\ \/ /\ || /\ \/ /\ |
|    \/    ||    \/    || \/    \/ || \/ /\ \/ |
|          || /\    /\ || /\    /\ || /\ \/ /\ |
|          || \/    \/ || \/    \/ || \/    \/ |
|__________||__________||__________||__________|

$ echo -n 10 3 4 2 6 | jconsole test.ijs
 __________  __________  __________  __________
| /\    /\ ||          ||          ||          |
| \/ /\ \/ || /\       || /\       || /\    /\ |
| /\ \/ /\ || \/       || \/       || \/    \/ |
| \/    \/ ||    /\    ||          || /\    /\ |
| /\    /\ ||    \/    ||          || \/    \/ |
| \/ /\ \/ ||       /\ ||       /\ || /\    /\ |
| /\ \/ /\ ||       \/ ||       \/ || \/    \/ |
|_\/____\/_||__________||__________||__________|

$ echo -n 5 10 5 2 3 | jconsole test.ijs
 __________  __________  __________  __________
| /\    /\ ||          ||          ||          |
| \/ /\ \/ || /\    /\ || /\       || /\       |
| /\ \/ /\ || \/    \/ || \/       || \/       |
| \/    \/ ||    /\    ||          ||    /\    |
| /\    /\ ||    \/    ||          ||    \/    |
| \/ /\ \/ || /\    /\ ||       /\ ||       /\ |
| /\ \/ /\ || \/    \/ ||       \/ ||       \/ |
|_\/____\/_||__________||__________||__________|
```

The core, finding the best hand, is actually really easy.  Generate the power set of the cards given, and select the one with the highest value less than 22.

```
({~[:(i.[:>./[*22&>)+/@>)(#:@i.@(2&^)@#<@#"1 _])
```

Then we start with a blank card

```
<>1 7 1#1&|.@(2 10&#)&.>' _';'| ';'|_'
```

and layer on diamonds in the appropriate places.

```
'/\/\'(x(<@:+)"1]4 2$1|.4#0 1)}y
```

The rest of the program is dominated by the table of what diamonds go where.

Comment: amazing algorithm, and amazing language, almost all of the codes are symbols

Answer (score 9):

## Python - 365 Characters

```
h=map(int,raw_input().split());H=len(h);R=range
for r in R(9):x=["| "[1>r]];print"".join("_ "[0<r<8].join(x+["  \//\__"[ord(('?'*11+'@'*8+'bb@BBbbbbbQY@AAQQQYYbfH@H@HbffYQD@D@DQQYfb@``bbbbfQY@PPQQQQQbf????????]]')[r*10+c])*2>>i&6:][:2]for i in 0,2,4]+x)for c in max([[h[b]for b in R(H)if n&1<<b]for n in R(1<<H)],key=lambda c:(sum(c)<22,sum(c),len(c),sorted(c),c)))
```

```
$ echo 2 4 8 1 8 3| python blackjack.py 
 __________  __________  __________  __________ 
|          ||          ||          ||          |
| /\       || /\    /\ || /\    /\ || /\       |
| \/       || \/ /\ \/ || \/ /\ \/ || \/       |
|          || /\ \/ /\ || /\ \/ /\ ||    /\    |
|          || \/ /\ \/ || \/ /\ \/ ||    \/    |
|       /\ || /\ \/ /\ || /\ \/ /\ ||       /\ |
|       \/ || \/    \/ || \/    \/ ||       \/ |
|__________||__________||__________||__________|
$ echo 1 4 5 4 7 4 8| python blackjack.py 
 __________  __________  __________  __________  __________ 
|          ||          ||          ||          ||          |
|          || /\    /\ || /\    /\ || /\    /\ || /\    /\ |
|          || \/    \/ || \/    \/ || \/ /\ \/ || \/    \/ |
|    /\    ||    /\    ||          || /\ \/ /\ ||          |
|    \/    ||    \/    ||          || \/    \/ ||          |
|          || /\    /\ || /\    /\ || /\    /\ || /\    /\ |
|          || \/    \/ || \/    \/ || \/    \/ || \/    \/ |
|__________||__________||__________||__________||__________|
```

**369 Characters**

```
h=map(int,raw_input().split());H=len(h);R=range;j=[]
for n in R(1<<H):c=[h[b]for b in R(H)if n&1<<b];j+=[(sum(c)<22,sum(c),len(c),sorted(c),c)]
for r in R(9):x=["| "[1>r]];print"".join("_ "[0<r<8].join(x+["  \//\__"[ord(('?'*11+'@'*8+'bb@BBbbbbbQY@AAQQQYYbfH@H@HbffYQD@D@DQQYfb@``bbbbfQY@PPQQQQQbf????????]]')[r*10+c])*2>>i&6:][:2]for i in 0,2,4]+x)for c in max(j)[-1])
```

**377 Characters**

```
h=map(int,raw_input().split());H=len(h);R=range;j=[]
for n in R(1<<H):c=[h[b]for b in R(H)if n&1<<b];j+=[(sum(c),len(c),sorted(c),c)]*(sum(c)<22)
T="@@@HD@@?@BA@@`P?@BAHD`P?@bQ@@bQ?@bQHDbQ?@bQbQbQ?@bYfQbQ?@bYfYfQ?bQbYfQb]bYfQbYf]"
for r in R(9):x=["| "[1>r]];print"".join("_ "[0<r<8].join(x+["  \//\__"[ord(('?'+T[c*8-8:])[r])*2>>i&6:][:2]for i in 0,2,4]+x)for c in max(j)[-1])
```

**408 characters**

```
h=map(int,raw_input().split());H=len(h);R=range;j=[]
for n in R(1<<H):c=[h[b]for b in R(H)if n&1<<b];j+=[(sum(c),len(c),sorted(c),c)]*(sum(c)<22)
T="@@@DH@@ @AB@@P` @ABDHP` @Qb@@Qb @QbDHQb @QbQbQb @QfYbQb @QfYfYb QbQfYbQn QfYbQfYn".split();U="\x3f"
for r in R(9):s="_ "[0<r<8];x=["| "[1>r]];print"".join(s.join(x+[("  ","/\\","\/","__")[ord((U+T[c-1]+U)[r])>>i&3]for i in 0,2,4]+x)for c in sorted(j)[-1][-1])
```

Comment: very cool! btw, If you change `\x3f` to `?` it will be 400 char, isnt it?

Comment: and if you hard-code, that `U+T[c-1]+U` to `"?"+T[c-1]+"?"`, it will be 398 Characters.

Comment: I'm curious if the Perl guys can beat this solution. It is very well-made imo.

Comment: beating Perl by 4 strokes for now.

Comment: Muahahaha, I shrunk the Perl by 8 characters, so it's once again (barely) shorter :D

Answer (score 4):

### [Perl](http://www.perl.org/)

Blatantly stolen from [gnibbler's Python solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1843182/1846600#1846600); turns out to be three characters shorter, at 362 -- if input is given on the  command line.

```
sub p{(local$z=pop)?(@z=&p,map[@$_,$z],@z):[]}
for(p@ARGV){$t=0;$t+=$_ for@$_;($s,@c)=($t,@$_)if$t>=$s&&$t<22}
for$r(0..8){$x=$r?'|':$";for$c(@c){print+join$r*($r<8)?$":'_',$x,
map(join('',((split//,'  \//\__')[ord((('?')x11,('@')x8,split//,
'bb@BBbbbbbQY@AAQQQYYbfH@H@HbffYQD@D@DQQYfb@``bbbbfQY@PPQQQQQbf????????]]'
)[$r*10+$c])*2>>$_&6..7])[0,1]),0,2,4),$x}print$/}
```

To read from stdin, replace `@ARGV` by `@F` and use `perl -an`; using traditional Perl golf scoring, that counts as 362.

And, of course, [gnibbler's other other Python trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1843182/1871680#1871680) can be copied too.

```
$ perl -pechomp <<'END' \
> >'bb@BBbbbbbQY@AAQQQYYbfH@H@HbffYQD@D@DQQYfb@``bbbbfQY@PPQQQQQbf????????]]'
> sub p{(local$z=pop)?(@z=&p,map[@$_,$z],@z):[]}
> for(p@F){$t=0;$t+=$_ for@$_;($s,@c)=($t,@$_)if$t>=$s&&$t<22}
> for$r(0..8){$x=$r?'|':$";for$c(@c){print+join$r*($r<8)?$":'_',$x,
> map(join('',((split//,'  \//\__')[ord((('?')x11,('@')x8,split//,$0)
> [$r*10+$c])*2>>$_&6..7])[0,1]),0,2,4),$x}print$/}
> END
$ wc -c <bb*
287
$ echo 10 5 2 9 3 | perl -an bb*
 __________  __________  __________ 
| /\    /\ ||          || /\    /\ |
| \/ /\ \/ || /\       || \/    \/ |
| /\ \/ /\ || \/       || /\    /\ |
| \/    \/ ||          || \/ /\ \/ |
| /\    /\ ||          || /\ \/ /\ |
| \/ /\ \/ ||       /\ || \/    \/ |
| /\ \/ /\ ||       \/ || /\    /\ |
|_\/____\/_||__________||_\/____\/_|
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1843182/code-golf-diamond-blackjack/1871680#1871680

Answer (score 3):

### Lua, 895

OK, correct now. Can even score 1 as ace.

```
t=table p=ipairs j=arg x={}r={}o={}b=0 function f()local e,s,n,m=0,0,{}for i,v in p(j)do s=s+v e=e+(v+0==1 and 1 or 0)n[i]=v end t.sort(n)for i,v in p(n)do if o[i]and v~=o[i]then m=v>o[i]break end end while e>0 and s<12 do s=s+10 e=e-1 end if s<=21 and s>b or(s==b and(#j>#r or(#j==#r and m)))then b=s for i=1,#r>#j and #r or #j do r[i]=j[i]o[i]=j[i]end t.sort(o)end if s>0 then for i=1,#j do t.insert(x,t.remove(j,i))f()t.insert(j,i,table.remove(x))end end end f()t={" __________ ","|          |","|__________|","|    /\\    |","| /\\       |","|       /\\ |","| /\\    /\\ |","| \\/ /\\ \\/ |","|_\\/____\\/_|"}c={"12224D223","125E226F3","125E4D6F3","127G227G3","127G4D7G3","127G7G7G3","1278HG7G3","1278H8HG3","17G78HG79","178HG78H9"}for i=1,9 do for j,x in p(r)do v=c[tonumber(x)]:sub(i,i):byte()io.write(v<64 and t[v-48]or(t[v-64]:gsub("[/\\]",{["/"]="\\",["\\"]="/"})))end io.write("\n")end
```

Sample output:

```
>lua card.lua 8 9 10 7 
 __________  __________ 
| /\    /\ || /\    /\ |
| \/    \/ || \/ /\ \/ |
| /\    /\ || /\ \/ /\ |
| \/ /\ \/ || \/    \/ |
| /\ \/ /\ || /\    /\ |
| \/    \/ || \/ /\ \/ |
| /\    /\ || /\ \/ /\ |
|_\/____\/_||_\/____\/_|

>lua card.lua 1 4 5 4 7 4 8 
 __________  __________  __________  __________  __________ 
|          ||          ||          ||          ||          |
|          || /\    /\ || /\    /\ || /\    /\ || /\    /\ |
|          || \/    \/ || \/    \/ || \/ /\ \/ || \/    \/ |
|    /\    ||    /\    ||          || /\ \/ /\ ||          |
|    \/    ||    \/    ||          || \/    \/ ||          |
|          || /\    /\ || /\    /\ || /\    /\ || /\    /\ |
|          || \/    \/ || \/    \/ || \/    \/ || \/    \/ |
|__________||__________||__________||__________||__________|

>lua card.lua 1 9 5 5
 __________  __________  __________
|          ||          ||          |
|          || /\    /\ || /\    /\ |
|          || \/    \/ || \/    \/ |
|    /\    ||    /\    ||    /\    |
|    \/    ||    \/    ||    \/    |
|          || /\    /\ || /\    /\ |
|          || \/    \/ || \/    \/ |
|__________||__________||__________|
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question? It says to output the optimised hand, not just the hand. So it should only print cards 10 and 9

Comment: I was thinking in hexadecimal... `0x8 + 0x9 + 0x10 = 0x21`

Comment: 1 4 5 4 7 4 8...shouldn't this be 1 5 7 8 as output?

Comment: @Scoregraphic, 1 5 4 7 4 is preferred as it has an extra card

Answer (score 2):

## Python - 298 Characters

simply rename the script like this

```
mv blackjack.py '???????????@@@@@@@@bb@BBbbbbbQY@AAQQQYYbfH@H@HbffYQD@D@DQQYfb@``bbbbfQY@PPQQQQQbf????????]].py'
```

Here is the script

```
import sys
h=map(int,raw_input().split());H=len(h);R=range
for r in R(9):x=["| "[1>r]];print"".join("_ "[0<r<8].join(x+["  \//\__"[ord(sys.argv[0][r*10+c])*2>>i&6:][:2]for i in 0,2,4]+x)for c in max([[h[b]for b in R(H)if n&1<<b]for n in R(1<<H)],key=lambda c:(sum(c)<22,sum(c),len(c),sorted(c),c)))
```

and a sample run

```
$ echo 1 2 3 4 5 | python '???????????@@@@@@@@bb@BBbbbbbQY@AAQQQYYbfH@H@HbffYQD@D@DQQYfb@``bbbbfQY@PPQQQQQbf????????]].py'
```

```
 __________  __________  __________  __________  __________ 
|          ||          ||          ||          ||          |
|          || /\       || /\       || /\    /\ || /\    /\ |
|          || \/       || \/       || \/    \/ || \/    \/ |
|    /\    ||          ||    /\    ||          ||    /\    |
|    \/    ||          ||    \/    ||          ||    \/    |
|          ||       /\ ||       /\ || /\    /\ || /\    /\ |
|          ||       \/ ||       \/ || \/    \/ || \/    \/ |
|__________||__________||__________||__________||__________|
```

Comment: Not counting command line length, eh?  Also, porting to Windows would require getting rid of the question marks though.  +1 for amusement anyways :D

Answer (score 1):

### Python, 632 characters

```
from itertools import*
o=sum;q=range;r=filter
l=map(int,raw_input().split())
s=r(lambda x:o(x)<22,chain.from_iterable(imap(combinations,repeat(l),q(len(l)+1))))
s=r(lambda x:o(x)==max(map(o,s)),s)
t=max(([(min(x),x)for x in s if len(x)==max(map(len,s))]))[1]
a=" __________ "
b="|          |"
c="| /\    /\ |";e=c[::-1]
d="| /\       |";l=d[::-1]
g="| \/       |";k=g[::-1]
i="|    /\    |";j=i[::-1]
h="| /\ \/ /\ |";f=h[::-1]
n="|_\/____\/_|"
m="|__________|"
y="aaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbccbddcccccefbggeeeffchibibichhfejbjbjeefhcbkkcccchefblleeeeechmmmmmmmmnn"
for x in q(9):
 print''.join([globals()[y[x*10:(x+1)*10][v-1]]for v in t])
```

Sample output:

```
10 5 7 4 1 1
 __________  __________  __________  __________  __________ 
| /\    /\ ||          ||          ||          ||          |
| \/ /\ \/ || /\    /\ || /\    /\ ||          ||          |
| /\ \/ /\ || \/    \/ || \/    \/ ||          ||          |
| \/    \/ ||    /\    ||          ||    /\    ||    /\    |
| /\    /\ ||    \/    ||          ||    \/    ||    \/    |
| \/ /\ \/ || /\    /\ || /\    /\ ||          ||          |
| /\ \/ /\ || \/    \/ || \/    \/ ||          ||          |
|_\/____\/_||__________||__________||__________||__________|
```

Comment: Fails with `2 4 8 1 8 3` giving 4,8,1,8 instead of 2,8,8,3.  According to the minimum of the minimum requirement.

Comment: Thanks for telling me. I've updated the version to correct this (and shaved off a few bytes ;-)

Answer (score 1):

#### Haskell minimally tested *721* characters

Updated Haskell version, now supposedly works for all cases but it could probably do with more testing.

```
import Data.List --17

--shorteners

m=map --6
r=reverse --10
l=length --9
u=True --7
g=minimum --10

--printing of the cards

p=foldl1(zipWith(++)).m d --26
a=[" __________ ","|          |","| /\\    /\\ |",r(a!!2),"| /\\       |",r(a!!4),"| \\/       |",r(a!!6),"|    /\\    |",r(a!!8),"| /\\ \\/ /\\ |",r(a!!10),"|_\\/____\\/_|","|__________|"] --190
j(Just x)=x --12
d(n+1)=m(j.(flip$lookup)(zip"abcedlgkijhfnm"a).("aaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbccbddcccccefbggeeeffchibibichhfejbjbjeefhcbkkcccchefblleeeeechmmmmmmmmnn"!!).(+n))[0,10..80] --160

-- interaction and pipeline

main=interact$unlines.p.f.m read.words --39
f x=head.filter((<22).sum).r.sortBy(o x)$x:z x --47

-- generate all possible hands (power set)

z[]=[] --7
z(x:s)=s:m(x:)(z s)++z s --25

-- sorting logic
c f a b=compare(f a)$f b --25

o x a b|l a==l b=s x a b|u=c l a b --35
s o a b|g a==g b=t o a b|u=c g a b --35
t o a b|all(`elem`b)a=c(n o)a b|u=GT --37
n t=m(j.(`elemIndex`t)) --24
```

---

Haskell version **not finished yet 622 characters**

it won't win any beauty contests, could also be improved I'm sure, and doesn't exactly follow the spec (still working on the `min(min(3,2), min(1,4))` issue as well as the duplicate filtering (the `o` function needs more cases)). Despite it's incompleteness it does pass all the test cases given.

Each line is commented (`--`) with the number of characters on it, including the new line.

```
import Data.List --17
p=foldl1(zipWith(++)).m d --26
r=reverse --10
a=[" __________ ","|          |","| /\\    /\\ |",r(a!!2),"| /\\       |",r(a!!4),"| \\/       |",r(a!!6),"|    /\\    |",r(a!!8),"| /\\ \\/ /\\ |",r(a!!10),"|_\\/____\\/_|","|__________|"] --190
j(Just x)=x --12
d(n+1)=m(j.(flip$lookup)(zip"abcedlgkijhfnm"a).("aaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbccbddcccccefbggeeeffchibibichhfejbjbjeefhcbkkcccchefblleeeeechmmmmmmmmnn"!!).(+n))[0,10..80] --160
m=map --6

main=interact$unlines.p.snd.f.m read.words --43

f x=head.filter((<22).fst).m(\x->(sum x,x))$r$sortBy o$x:z x --61

c f a b=compare(f a)$f b --25
z[]=[] --7
z(x:s)=s:m(x:)(z s)++z s --25
l=length --9

o a b|l a==l b=GT|True=c l a b --31
```

Comment: sounds like it pukes and likes it ;)

Comment: Using the pre-Hierarchical Libraries, `import List` shaves off 5 chars.  `r l=l:reverse l:[];a=[" __________ ","|          |"]++(["| /\\    /\\ |","| /\\       |","| \\/       |","|    /\\    |","| /\\ \\/ /\\ |"]>>=r)++["|_\\/____\\/_|","|__________|"]` shaves off 20 characters, but rearranging it (and the string constants to match) could probably save more.  Reordering your characters so that you can use `zip['a'..]` would save 9 characters.  `c f=(.f).compare.f` saves 6 characters.

Comment: `f=head.filter((<22).fst).m(\x->(sum x,x)).r.sortBy o.m concat.mapM(\x->[[x],[]])` and eliminate `z` to remove 12 characters.  I think that's about it for the low-lying fruit.

Comment: i could also try using the blank card + diamond placement encoding from your J solution, I've got some time tonight to take a stab at these improvements and more.  I also want to get my list ordering 100% correct.

Answer (score 1):

### Perl, 410 char

Don't know how much more improvement is possible, but maybe this would be easier to port to GolfScript than gnibbler's algorithm:

```
sub R{for(@_){substr$q[$_],$B+$z,2,'/\\';substr$q[$_+1],$B+$z,2,'\/';
if($B==2){$B=8;R(8-$_);$B=2}}}
for$i(1..1<<(@p=@ARGV)){$s=$n=0;$i&1<<$n++&&($s+=21*$_+1)for@p;
$q=$s,$N=$i if$s<462&&$q<$s}
@q=($/)x9;for$p(grep$N&1<<$_,0..@p){
s/$/|          |/for@q;
$B=5;($P=$p[$p])&1&&R(4-($P==7));$P-8||R 5,3;$P>9&&R 6,2;
$B=2;if($P>8){R 1,3,5,7}else{R 2if$P>1;R 6if$P>3;R 4if$P>5}$z+=12}
$q[0]=~y/| / _/;$q[-1]=~y/ /_/;print@q
```